# How to add a class to a div at one condition?

Tags: jquery, html, class, jsrender, jsviews

I have a number, a, which gets at each 3 secs a random value from 0 to 100.

```
            <div class="industrial gauge size two warning">
                <span class="ticks" data-amount="8" data-scale-freq="1"></span>
                <div class="space"></div>
                <div class="meter"></div>
            </div>
```

For example when a>80 I wanna add a class, named "danger", to the first div. How could I do this?

Comment: what `JS` or `jQuery` did you used to achieve that counter or gauge?

Comment: Why? Does it matter? The counter I generate like this:  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

Comment: Are you using JsViews and JsRender? If so you can use data-linking, but if not then the jsrender and jsviews tags don't belong on this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div an id for example

```
<div id="first" class="space"></div>
```

and use this code at Jquery

```
   if(a>80)
{
    $("#first").addClass('danger');
}
```

Or I recommend for you to write as many CSS classes as you want and change the attribute class in any condition you like

```
   if(a>80)
{
    $("#first").attr('class', 'newClass');
}
```

Comment: Sounds logic, but doesn't work. When I add "danger" class, my thank's background color should get red.

Comment: Now I understand that you want to change the class not adding another one?